# php macro try escaping

Tags: php, sql

try escaping them

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Timestamp' (T_STRING) in
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\NetMake\v81\wwwroot\scriptcase\app\Pong8\blank\index.php on line
>   1079

```
sc_exec_sql("CREATE TABLE StepOneSection as
SELECT

public.pong8.\"Timestamp\",
public.pong8.\"Last\",
public.pong8.\"Trade Price\",
public.pong8.\"Trade Volume\",
public.pong8.\"Best Bid\",
public.pong8.\"Bid Size\",
public.pong8.\"Best Ask\",
public.pong8.\"Ask Size\",
public.pong8.\"Turnover\"
FROM
Public.pong8
") ;
```

Comment: Use single quotes instead?

Comment: AFAIK, mysql by default uses backticks ` for field names, not double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

asuming you use MySQL, you have to delimit your field names with backticks.
usually you don't have to delimit them at all, but since your field names contain spaces (don't do that the next time), delimiting is necessary.

as far as other DBMS' go, i'm not certain, but it should behave similarly.
in general, databases are very picky about what kind of quote you use where.

```
sc_exec_sql("CREATE TABLE StepOneSection as
SELECT

public.pong8.`Timestamp`,
public.pong8.`Last`,
public.pong8.`Trade Price`,
public.pong8.`Trade Volume`,
public.pong8.`Best Bid`,
public.pong8.`Bid Size`,
public.pong8.`Best Ask`,
public.pong8.`Ask Size`,
public.pong8.`Turnover`
FROM
Public.pong8
") ;
```